# Setting a button's size according to a dynamic custom view's size

Tags: android, custom-controls

1. CalendarBackground is a custom view which implements onDraw() and onMeasure(). Its size is dynamic, calculated in onMeasure().
2. CalendarView is another custom view which extends the following RelativeLayout.

   ```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>  
   <RelativeLayout 
       xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"  
       android:orientation="vertical"  
       android:layout_width="fill_parent"  
       android:layout_height="fill_parent">  

       <lc.test.CalendarBackground  
           android:id="@+id/calBg"  
           android:layout_width="fill_parent"  
           android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>  

       <Button  
           android:id="@+id/prevMonth"  
           android:text="@string/prev_month"   
           android:layout_width="wrap_content"   
           android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>  
   </RelativeLayout>
   ```
3. The button prevMonth's position & size should be decided by CalendarBackground, so I need to change its size after CalendarBackground.onMeasure() is invoked.

I know how to change a button's size by setting its LayoutParams pragmatically, but I don't know where should I put these codes? It cannot be in CalendarView's constructor, because the code there is invoked before CalendarBackground.onMeasure()...

Thanks a lot!

---

As I cannot answer my own question, I put the answer here:

I got it. Override the onLayout method of the CalendarView class, and set the button's size there.

This is the code of CalendarBackground.onMaesure:

```
@Override
protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {

    //Get canvas width and height
    wCalendar = MeasureSpec.getSize(widthMeasureSpec);
    hCalendar = 7*MeasureSpec.getSize(heightMeasureSpec)/10;
    setMeasuredDimension(wCalendar, hCalendar);
}
```

This is code of CalendarView.onLayout:

```
@Override
protected void onLayout(boolean changed, int left, int top, int right, int bottom) {
    super.onLayout(changed, left, top, right, bottom);
    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams lp = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(prevMonth.getLayoutParams());
    lp.width = (right - left)/7;
    lp.height = (bottom - top)/7;
    prevMonth.setLayoutParams(lp);      
}
```

The result is exactly what I want. This onLayout is invoked after CalendarBackground.onMeasure().

However, I observed another question. That is the execution sequence:
4 times CanlendarBackground.onMaesure(), then CalendarView.onLayout(), then another 4 times CanlendarBackground.onMaesure(), then another CalendarView.onLayout(), then CanlendarBackground.onDraw().

Is there anything wrong with my code? I mean this sequence doesn't make sense. CanlendarBackground.onMaesure() is invoked 8 times, and CalendarView.onLayout() is invoke 2 times, although the execution result is what I want.

Answer (score 0):

There is size interdependence. Therefore depending on the device the size of the view will change. You have to modify the android manifest file for that. Have a look at developers.android... website